# How to express a regular expression?

Tags: regex

How to express a regular expression over the alphabet `{a, b, c}` that doesn't contain the contiguous sub-string `baa`?

Answer (score 2):

If your regex flavor supports [negative lookaheads](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html), then it's relatively simple. E.g. in php it looks like this:

```
^^(?:(?!baa)[abc])*$
```

Demo [here](https://regex101.com/r/zyjcSZ/2).

Explanation:

- `^...$` makes sure we match the entire line
- `[abc]` is a character class that defines the alphabet
- `(?!baa)` is the negative lookahead. It checks for every position if it is followed by `baa`. If it is, then it's not a match
- finally, we group these two with a non-capturing group: `(?:...)` and repeat them as many times as fits into the line: `(?:...)*`

#### Update

Updated the demo and the regex according to [ClasG](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2064981/clasg) -s comment. Indeed, to make sure it fails for a simple `baa`, the lookahead must come first, then the character class.

Comment: [`^(?:[abc](?!baa))*$`](https://regex101.com/r/2jIewo/1/) matches `baa`.

Comment: Swap the tests - `^(?:(?!baa)[abc])*$` and it'll work. I.e. look-ahead prior to character class.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew The question isn't a dup of the Q you say (though it lacks a lot). To use the answer, it may be helpful though.

Comment: @ClasG thanks, updated